# Using for loop within if statements in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I am really having a hard time with loop statements for python, please see below:

I want it to check the users age, so if they are over 18, it will say "old enough, if they are over 16, it will say "almost there" and if they are younger than this, it will say "sorry you're too young"

I got the following code below:

```
age = int(raw_input("Enter your age:"))

if age >= 18:
    print "You are old enough!"
elif age >= 16:
    print "Almost there"
else:
    print "You're just too young"
```

my problem is, how do I write code the includes an if statement and a for loop that will print out all the numbers from 0 that are less than the user's inputted age?

do I say:

```
for age in range (0,num) 
    if num <= age
    print ....
else:
    print...
```

Please kindly help. I'm new at this and still learning :(

Comment: Tip: Switch `age` and `num` in your loop. (You also don't need another `if..else` in there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you could construct a variable that contains a list of numbers that is smaller than the user's age. You can construct this using python's [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function; something like `range(age)` would do this nicely.

Then you need to use a [for loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) to loop through all these numbers and print them to the command line. Something like `for x in range(age)` would be a good place to start.

Then, in the loop, you'd just need to turn x from an integer into a string using the [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) function, and print it to the command line.

So as pseudo-code:

```
if the age is greater than 18:
    print that they're old enough
else if the age is greater than 16:
    print that they're nearly old enough 
otherwise:
    print that they're not old enough.

for each number between 0 and age:
    print the number
```

Come back when you have some code and we can help you with any trouble you have.

Comment: You can also print that numbers in one line: `print ' '.join([x for x in xrange(age)])`

Comment: I just wanted to show them the most straightforward and easy to understand way, since they're a beginner, but that's certainly a good one to know.